# Iterating over queryset values

Tags: python, django

I wrote a little app that allows users to create their own excel reports. One of my queries unpacks a list to `.values()` to return the columns. The problem I am having is trying to iterate/reference those values returned as I don't know what values are included in the report.

Here is my attempt:

```
queryset = Claim.objects.filter(client=client, creation__year=year, creation__month=month)\
            .values(*values).order_by('id')

for i, c in enumerate(queryset):
    for ii, r in enumerate(c):
         print c
```

I get

```
 TypeError: 'Claim' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact code you are running? When you use `values()` you are iterating over a queryset of dicts, so you shouldn't get `'Claim' object is not iterable`. Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is your 5th line `for ii, r in enumerate(c):` you CANNOT enumerate a `Model` type.

You CAN quit while you're ahead on the first loop. (I dont understand why the second loop is there..)

```
for i, c in enumerate(queryset):
    print i, c, type(c)
```

and you'll get something like:

```
0 {[some dict data]} <dict>
1 {[some dict data]} <dict>
2 {[some dict data]} <dict>
3 {[some dict data]} <dict>
....
```

Comment: For example. In the first loop I iterate over the queryset so I can access `c.first_name` and get the `first_name` value. Due to the user passing in there own values in .values(), I can not reference by 'c.firstname'. I am struggling to come up with another way to reference them, either by index or iteration

Comment: @Mantis Oh i see your issue, the values() turns it into a `dict`, you wont be able to do  `c.first_name`, you will have to do `c['first_name']` or `c.get('first_name')` -- but still, one loop.

Comment: Sorry. I don't think I was very clear on my question. You did jog my memory though with saying values() turns it into a dict. It was values_list() I needed so I could `c[0]` for example

Comment: @Mantis if its values_list() yes, it is a list, and you lose all the `headers` if you will. You will have to keep track of that yourself, and it can get a bit harry. So you want to essentially loop over a dataset and then over the "values" one by one? -- and then what?

Answer (score 3):

Here **Bankdetails is an imaginary** model, Here is an easy solution to iterate over the query set

```
from django.core import serializers
object_list = serializers.serialize("python", Bankdetails.objects.all())
for object in object_list:
    for field_name, field_value in object['fields'].items():
        print (field_name,'->', field_value)
    print()
```

**Output**

```
email -> rahul@gmail.com
name -> RAHUL
fullname -> Rahul Kushwaha
cardno -> 1764987364892637
expm -> 02
cvv -> 343
expy -> 2022
address -> RZ-B
city -> New Delhi

email -> seema@gmail.com
name -> SEEMA
fullname -> Seema Kumari
cardno -> 123456789120393
expm -> 08
cvv -> 56
expy -> 2023
address -> HK/L
city -> New Delhi
```

*To understand more you can visit here*
https://btechcse762.blogspot.com/2020/11/different-ways-to-perform-operations-on.html

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Javier Buzzi i was able to realise my mistake. I needed values_list() not values().

```
queryset = Claim.objects.filter(client=client, creation__year=year, creation__month=month)\
            .values_list(*values).order_by('id')

for i, c in enumerate(queryset):
         print q[i]
```

Comment: Just glad you got it ;)